# Android : Hand gesture recognition using camera

Tags: android

I want the android phone camera to recognise the hand gestures and also assign the operation for an individual gesture if the camera recognise that gesture it shud perform that specifed operation.
          Thank you please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Try exploring the OpenCV library it might help you with this. Visit opencv.org

Answer (score 0):

The Android library HandWave has the functionality you're looking for. Have you looked into it at all?